# Java PriorityQueue.remove() time complexity? O(log N) or O(N)?

Tags: java, priority-queue

PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
Assuming the priorityQueue pq has size N, what is the time complexity for pq.remove()?

Is it O(log N) or O(N)?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) before asking?

Comment: it's linear time.

Comment: @PalaniSriram *if the Oracle JVM is used.

Comment: remove() function is to remove the head/root, it takes O(logN) time and remove(Object o) is to remove an object so, finding this obj takes O(N) time, and removing it takes O(logN) time.

Answer (score 6):

From [the documentation of `PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> [...]
>
> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the enqueuing and dequeuing methods (`offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and `add`); linear time for the `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)` methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods (`peek`, `element`, and `size`).
>
> [...]

One should, however, point out that this is not part of any interface-contract. Thus, it is an implementation detail. As such, it could change without prior notice or when using a non-Oracle JDK and should therefore not be relied upon.